# Simple general exception handling in async code without boilerplate

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation-token

We start using CancellationToken in out app a lot, so we have to change exception handling correspondingly:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100);
        await DoJob(cts.Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully finished");
    }

    private static async Task DoJob(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
        }
        catch (Exception e) when(!(e is OperationCanceledException))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do cleanup in case of error.");
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind this code is that if someone use catch(Exception e) (please do not blame me for this) and forgot to exclude CancellationToken, an error handling is executed, for example, there is a log that operation failed. But it is not true, id doesn't fail, it just has been canceled. And cancellation should be handled differently then failure.

It seems to me like a big boilerplate to write practically in every general catch

```
catch (Exception e) when(!(e is OperationCanceledException))
```

Is there some more robust solution with less boilerplate?

Comment: Create a method that catches the exception?

Comment: In general, you just shouldn't try to handle such a broad error like `Exception` at this method level. Replace your `catch (Exception e) when (!(e is OperationCancelledException))` with any **anticipated** exceptions, which could be thrown by the called code.

Comment: It seems, it's `Main` method which should process exceptions (`DoJob` can have `finally`)

Comment: @Yeldar, yes, there are specific exception if possible. But be realistic, look into any codebase and you will find general exceptiont there as well. And even if there could be general exceptionhandling, I cannot rewrite all legacy code if I am going to add CancellationToken. Or do you?

Comment: I find this use case odd: if an operation is canceled, why would you *not* want to clean up after it's canceled?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a method that accepts a `Func<Task>` and catches the exception(s), e.g.:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100);
        await GeneralDoJobAndCatchException(() => DoJob(cts.Token));
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully finished");
    }

    private static async Task GeneralDoJobAndCatchException(Func<Task> func)
    {
        try
        {
            await func();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do error handling");
        }
    }

    private static async Task DoJob(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're having the exact same problem. Mainly there is a `while`-loop that checks for the `CancellationToken` but you've to catch this exception.

We created the following extension method:

```
public static async Task<TaskStatus> HideCancellationException(this Task task)
{
    try
    {
        await task;
        return task.Status;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return TaskStatus.Canceled;
    }
}
```

Having this extension method allows to change this code:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // do stuff here...

    try
    {   
        await Task.Delay(..., cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // expected
    }
}
```

to something like that:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // Do stuff here.

    await Task.Delay(..., cancellationToken).HideCancellationException();
}
```

Keep in mind that there is explicitly no overload for `Task<T>` because the return value in case of cancellation is `default`. You can't distinguish between `default` as normal task result and `default` as result of cancellation. In that case it's better to catch the exception.

Comment: The [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception) inherits from the `OperationCanceledException`. So catching the second catches also the first.

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the try-catch block altogether by awaiting indirectly with [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany), and then querying the status of the completed task:

```
private static async Task DoJob(CancellationToken ct)
{
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(1000, ct));
    if (completedTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + completedTask.Exception.InnerException);
    }
    else if (completedTask.IsCanceled)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    else // Success
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```